# User file cannot be parsed in subversion in MAC iphone SDK

Tags: iphone

i am new to iphone ...
 just updated my project with Subversion and now, if I try to open the project, I get that error: "Unable to open project /Users/dualg4/DEV/MacStubs/MacStubs.xcodeproj cannot be opened because the user file cannot be parsed"
Where can I find it?

How can I get my project to load again?
any help??????????

Answer (score 13):

Open project.pbxproj in text editor and check special svn marks & remove them

Comment: you want to take the project file, <YOUR-PROJECT-NAME>.xcodeproj , and right click on it. Select "show package contents". That will show you the project.pbxproj file. This is what you open in a text editor.

Answer (score 9):

Slim's answer is correct:

Look for the SVN marks in project.pbxproj file... remove them and it will parse correctly.

See my before and after:

BEFORE:

```
     1325                                   238A69591382B45C00494480 /* HUDLayer.m in Sources,
     1326   <<<<<<< .mine
     1327                                   23D080F313835E8C004F0E5C /* GameSummaryViewController.m in Sources */,
     1328   =======
     1329                                   1023605613843E070058620A /* segmentedTimer.m in Sources */,
     1330   >>>>>>> .r121
     1331
```

AFTER:

```
     1325                                   238A69591382B45C00494480 /* HUDLayer.m in Sources */,
     1326                                   23D080F313835E8C004F0E5C /* GameSummaryViewController.m in Sources */,
     1327                                   23F2D5E2138484EE00421AEF /* segmentedTimer.m in Sources */,
     1328                           );
```

This will parse fine. Open in Xcode and commit the project.pbxproj to SVN. This is for Xcode 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a conflict in your project.pbxproj file (inside MacStubs.xcodeproj).  When that file has a conflict, it's usually best to revert it and make your changes to it again.

Comment: will you explain how to revert it step by step please?

Comment: Perhaps you should read the SVN documentation a little more if you're going to be using it regularly. Basic knowledge of source control systems is a definite must when developing software.
If you're using the svn command line client, then type svn --help