# Xcode cannot parse exported project from Unity 4 after being upgraded from unity 3

Tags: ios, xcode, parsing, unity-game-engine

We upgraded a 9 month old Unity project, which is currently on the appstore, to `Unity` 4.1, and after the conversion, when we export the `Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj` in Xcode, we get the following error:

```
Project cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed.
```

We already tried the solutions here:

[Unable to open project... cannot be opened because the project file cannot be parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361799/xcode-unable-to-open-project-cannot-be-opened-because-the-project-file-canno)

Has anyone else ever had this parse error when trying to open an xcode project after being exported from Unity?

Comment: if your ios project is under version control, there could be some conflicts. anyway, open your project file with any text editor. try find ">>", "==" or "<<". It is just an xml file and such a symbols don't allow to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Some Unity packages install editor scripts that modify the XCode project after it's generated.  These scripts can cause the symptom described, if they have a bug, or if they subtly interfere with each other.  Search your project for OnPostprocessBuild calls, try disabling them one-by-one, generate a fresh XCode project each time, and see if it starts opening with XCode.

If it does start working, diff the working and non-working versions of Unity-iPhone/project.pbxproj, and see if you can figure out why.