# The project ‘project’ is damaged and cannot be opened due to a parse error. Examine the project file for invalid edits... control conflicts

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I am trying to merge master into my feature branch, and presented with this error. I have looked around the internet, and also tried to debug this issue myself including playing around with the `.pbxproj` file's conflicts (which showed none). All paths I have taken has not been fruitful. I am kindly asking for any direction I should take (i.e. which files to look at). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Almost impossible to say but look at the dates for the files inside your .xcodeproj to see if any of them have a completely different (later) change date. Then it is probably that file that has been changed. In worst case, create a new project and move over all your source files, storyboard etc

Comment: @JoakimDanielson have you dealt with the problem before? It seems you're very knowledgeable about the iOS environment, and I'm leaning toward migrating new files into my master vs merging master into my branch.

Comment: Looks like you have changed the question somewhat, maybe this is a git issue as noted in the answer below.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it is. apologies. The answer below, though expectedly the right answer, but in this case, I am not seeing those conflict lines. Without those, I am not able to debug properly?

Comment: Well I don't really understand the correlation between the merging and the error message

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I see. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Those finding this SO post first should also check out the following older but still relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361799/unable-to-open-project-cannot-be-opened-because-the-project-file-cannot-be-pa

Answer (score 43):

If you're using git to merge branches, this can happen when there are conflicts that aren't properly resolved. Open the `.pbxproj` and delete any conflict markers:

```
<<<<<<<
=======
>>>>>>>
```

Comment: When i try delete them they reappear.

Answer (score 4):

[image]In my case it is because of a "\" in path attribute. I changed it to "/" and I used "plutil -lint project.pbxproj" to find the line number on which error was.

Comment: would you provide more details ?

Comment: because of "\" in path it was not working after changing it to "/" it worked.

Answer (score 2):

- Right click on yourProject.xcodeproj
- Choose the option called **Show Package Contents**
- Open the **.pbxproj** file
- Delete / fix the conflicts

**Note:** You should see these conflict markers in **.pbxproj** file

```
<<<<<<<
=======
>>>>>>>
```

**See the pictures**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. find your pbxproj file:  YourProject/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
2. Compare this file to your last successful run of the project
3. fix the difference part and try again !

**Good luck!**